# Identical code generates error in one project, but not another

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I am trying to reuse code from another project, but while copying the classes over, it generated a compiler error in the new project, but while it was in the other project, it worked just fine.

The error is

```
    Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'const uint8_t *' (aka 'const unsigned char *') with an rvalue of type 'const void *'
```

and the code is

```
    [outputStream write:[userdata bytes] maxLength:[userdata length]];
```

outputStream is an NSOutputStream, and userdata is an NSData object.
The same code surrounding this statement is used in both projects.

Both projects are compiling for the same target OS( iOS 5.0) and archetecture(armv7), and both have identical frameworks added.

I also tried to clean the project, and build it again. Same problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried removing -Werr, -Wall, -Wextra, or -pedantic switches from the compiler flags?

Comment: I haven't added them to either project, and Xcode would likely have added them to both projects, if it added them to one.

Comment: Jumping in VERY late, and having had a similar issue to yours, it turns out that methods may not be compiled if no one calls them. So may have had one project not calling that particular code, and another does. [More](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15213415/1179377).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, this was solved by casting:

```
[outputStream write:(const uint8_t *)[userdata bytes] maxLength:[userdata length]];
```

followed by a clean and build (without cleaning, it would come up with a different error.)

Comment: This worked for me. Didn't require clean, am on LLVM 4.1. Xcode 4.5.2.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the old project is using the GCC compiler, and the new project is using LLVM. So the error is coming from the Clang front-end. If you change your compiler to GCC or LLVM GCC, it should go away.

Comment: No, they both use Apple LLVM 3.0. The old project was created with the same version of Xcode, on the same computer, just a few weeks ago.

Comment: In that case it may be an error somewhere else. Have you tried commenting out the line that causes the error and rebuilding?

Comment: Yeah, I commented out the line, and the code compiles (But, of course, is non-functional)

Comment: Got me stumped then without seeing the whole project myself, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, casting is what's needed, and the best way to do it is:

```
[outputStream write:static_cast<const uint8_t *>([userdata bytes]) maxLength:[userdata length]];
```